# Thread-Safe Ruby Queue with .each/iterator

Tags: ruby, concurrency, iterator, thread-safety, queue

Looking at [Queue API](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Queue.html), I don't think it has a `#each` implementation or any sort of iteration run.  Is there anyway we can convert the thread-safe Queue to an array or a list without manipulating any elements inside the Queue? (Let's assume this queue is immutable.)

Maybe I didn't search Google well, but couldn't find anything relevant to this with thread-safe operation.

Any reply is much appreciated.

Comment: I figure that they don't expose that kind of functionality because it would defeat the purpose of the queue. Making sure that one and only one consumer can pop a given element from the queue is what it does. If something can get the entire queue as an iterable object that thing can wreak havok, since we can basically never assume that anything in Ruby is immutable. Maybe you can find some alternative implementation?

Comment: Here's a related discussion on the difficulties of iteration over a Queue: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1539664

Comment: @Jesper I disagree. There's definitely an use case for looking at all elements in a queue without `pop()` each FIFO item one-by-one.  I'm sure it's difficult, so I'm looking for any other alternative.

Comment: I didn't mean that there isn't a reason why you'd want to do something like that, but I'd argue that just because there's a use case doesn't mean it is wise to add the functionality.

Comment: Sure, I'm here look for other tricks or alternative ways for similar operation, not asking ruby core team change implementation

Comment: @Jesper: link broken. do you remember how did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

The [Hamster gem](https://github.com/hamstergem/hamster) offers a number of immutable data structures, among them a form of queue - Deque.

The Deque doesn't implement `each`, but it can be converted to a List, which is iterable.

```
require 'hamster/deque'

q = Hamster::Deque[1,2,3]
q.to_list.each { |n| puts n }
# => 1
# => 2
# => 3
```

NB: Deque is available in the `v1.0.1` release candidates. This version hasn't been released yet. Older versions of Hamster don't include Deque, but have some kind of Queue which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I'm not sure who gives the idea to Hamster dev, but it returns a new deque on every push()? that doesn't make sense at all

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hamstergem/hamster/master/Hamster/Deque

```Return a new Deque with item added at the end.```

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense. The deque would not be immutable if adding a new element would mutate the original deque.